# Fixing constants of a series solution of a fourth-order PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, power-series

The following is the PDE I want to solve,
$$\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}y_{xxxx}+8x\left(1+x^{2}\right)y_{xxx} + 4\left(1+3x^{2}\right)y_{xx} + K\left[2x yy_{xx}+\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(yy_{xxx} + y_{x}y_{xx}\right) - 4(1+3x^{2})y_{xxK} - 4x(1+x^{2})y_{xxxK}\right]=0,\tag{1}$$

This is a fourth-order nonlinear PDE whose boundary conditions read

$$x=0: y_{x} = 0, y+Ky_{K}=0;\ x\to\infty: y_{x}\to1,y+Ky_{K}\to x $$

The following Ansatz satisfies the boundary conditions at $x=0$
$$y(x) = \sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(K)b_{m}(x)\tag{2},$$
where
$$  a_{n}(K) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\zeta_{n,i}K^{i},\\
     b_{n}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\lambda_{m,j}\left(x\ \tan^{-1}\left( x^{j}\right) - \frac{jx^{j+1}}{j+1}\  _{2}F_{1}\left[\frac{j+1}{2j},1;\frac{1}{2}\left(3+\frac{1}{j} \right);-x^{2j}\right] \right).$$
Here, $\zeta_{n,i}$ and $\lambda_{m,j}$ are constants. with $x\to\infty$ the ansatz yields the following relations between the series constants,
$$ \sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\zeta_{n,i}K^{i}\left(\frac{\lambda_{m,0}}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{m,j} \right) = \frac{2}{\pi}\tag{3}, $$
$$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\zeta_{n,i}K^{i}\lambda_{m,0} + \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{m,n =0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i\zeta_{n,i}K^{i}\left(\frac{\lambda_{m,0}}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{m,j} \right) = x\tag{4}.$$
How do I determine the series constants (up to a summation index of $2$)? I couldn't do the same via Mathematica and hand calculations by plugging the ansatz into the PDE seem too messy (but I believe there must be a simpler way which I can't seem to figure out). Since I am interested in solutions only up to a summation index of $2$, I can rely on the equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ to help me find relations between the $0,1,2$ index constants but I can't seem to go further.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a PDE: I see only derivations respect to the $x$ variable, therefore I'd expect it to be a ODE and your problem to be a boundary value problem for an higher order ODE. Could you clarify this point?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Just saw that I didn't copy the PDE correctly from my LaTeX script. It is a PDE and I have appended the terms dependent on "K". Sorry about that.